# UIStatusBarStyleLightContent Not setting battery white?

Tags: ios, ios7, statusbar, uistatusbar

I am using programatically setting my status bar white with :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

However the battery icon is still green? Where Apples example shows the battery being white when applying this style? See there example [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html).

Any idea how to change the battery from green to white?  :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

the battery is only green while its charging. unplug and it will be fine

as an aside, if you are on "low Power Mode" in newer iOS versions, the battery is Yellow not white

Comment: LOL - sometimes it's the simple things. :) Of course we all have our devices plugged in while working on an app so we can install builds.

Comment: Yea - never really thought of that! HAHAHAHA! Hilarious.